# Does iOS Mail block the inline use of "-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"?

Tags: ios, css, html-email, font-size, apple-mail

I am creating a email signature with HTML markup, and to match the design, I have to shrink the `font-size` property to under 11px, which is the lowest limit put by iOS mail rendering.

An article from Campaign Monitor suggested the use of the vendor specific property `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` to get around that:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3339/save-your-layout-by-overriding-the-minimum-font-size-on-the-iphone-and/

However, the demo is using the `<style>` inside the `<head>` tag. But when it's done in inline style it does not seem to work on iOS anymore:

`<a href="http://www.example.com" style="font-size:10px;color:#000;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Example</a>`

I have seen some signature using `<font size="1">Small Text</font>`, but it seems that the `<font>` tag is deprecated now.

So is there still any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the webkit CSS in your `<style>` tag. iOS mail and Android's default client respect style tags, and it won't affect any other client.

The font tag is deprecated, but i find it's still the most reliable across clients like Outlook '07-'13 and Windows Phone.

Comment: As a side note, `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` doesn't affect the gmail app no matter where you put it. If you find a way to keep it from resizing text please let us know!

Comment: Do you mean I should use the `<style>` tag even outside the `<head>` tag? I ask because it is a email signature, which would be placed at the end of every email, so does not really make sense to have a `<head>` there?

Comment: Yeah, I actually use `<style>` outside in the body for all my emails. Most clients will strip your `head` anyway, and the others will ignore the second one if you have two `head`s.

Comment: @ZephyrusDigital, to fix the Gmail iOS font resizing issue, refer to this blog for a fix: http://freshinbox.com/blog/gmail-ios-increases-email-font-sizes-again/